# Como documentar parâmetros recebidos pela função "func_get_args"?

Tags: php, php-doc, php-document

Como eu posso estar documentando parâmetros que são recebidos através da função `func_get_args`?

O motivo é de estar podendo passar vários parâmetros para a função com a mesma finalidade!

```php
/**
 * Gets a smart text filtered and formatted of according with the property name provided
 *
 * @param string $code The property name to be called
 *
 * @return string Returns the content of property in `$code` with formatting filter as a string
 * @see   Skreth\Code\Text::getTexts()
 * @since 0.2
 */
public static function code($code)
{
    if (!is_string($code)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Smart text is not a string");

    return StringFilter::formatting(self::getTexts($code));
}
```

Como assim, podendo ser possível passar vários `$code`:

```php
public static function code()
{
    $code = func_num_args();
    $result = [];

    foreach ($code as $value) {
        if (!is_string($value)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Smart text is not a string");

        $result[] =  StringFilter::formatting(self::getTexts($value));
    }

    // OU, TALVEZ (Acredito que foreach seja mais perfomático, estou certo?)...
    $result = array_map(function ($value) {
        if (!is_string($value)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Smart text is not a string");

        return StringFilter::formatting(self::getTexts($value));
    }, $code);

    return implode(' ', $result);
}
```

Aceito dicas de boas práticas de programação também :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336702/1518921)

A maneira antiga seria:

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html

```
/**
 * @param int $param,...
 **/
```

No entanto isto não é mais suportado, Desde o PHP5.6 os Variadic Method Parameters são parte do PHP e o PHPDoc também fez a atualização pra isto. Parece funcionar no PhpStorm IDE desde o EAP 139.659 (8.0.2+). Não tenho certeza sobre outros IDEs.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20157

Em todos casos a sintaxe apropriada é esta:

```
/**
 * @param int ...$param
 **/
```